# MySQL Indexing | Using it with LIKE

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table say "abcd"

The contents are as follows

```
ID | email       | 

24 | abcd@g.com  | 
23 | asdsa@gm.com|
32 |asd@ggm.com  |
```

Now  , i've created an index on (ID,email)

When I execute the query ,
    EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM abcd WHERE ID='23'; 
I can see that the index is being used.

However , when i change the query to
    EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM abcd WHERE ID LIKE '2%';

the index isnt being used anymore

Why is this so ? Shouldn't the index be used in both the cases ?

Thanks

Comment: How many rows are there in your table? Can you post the output of EXPLAIN SELECT?

Comment: for the 2nd query did you mean this: `SELECT * FROM abcd WHERE ID LIKE '2%'` ?

Comment: What is the type of the ID column? Integer or string?

Comment: Also what Storage Engine are you using?

Comment: @MarkByers this is the output http://codetidy.com/2886/

Comment: @Anant: Why is your index called `email_extid` instead of `extid_email`? Did you add the columns to the index in the wrong order?  Can you please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE abcd` and add the output from that to your question? Also, why do you have only two columns but three indexes? Do you have more columns that you haven't told us about? Again, posting `SHOW CREATE TABLE abcd` will answer this question, so please do that as soon as possible.

Comment: I added the index after i created the table. The index was in the order (ID,email)

Comment: @Anant: Why is the name incorrect? Obviously MySQL won't care about the name, but it's very confusing for humans to try to use database where the indexes with incorrect or misleading names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ID has an integer type, its index won't work like a string index: it will not use the decimal digits internally, but a fixed-length binary representation

Think about it: '2%' must match these numbers:

```
2
20
200
2000
...
```

But it is not exactly trivial for MySQL engine to match '2%' against these representations:

```
0x0002
0x0014
0x00C8
0x07D0
0x4E20
...
```

While theoretically it could convert the '2%' pattern internally to the following:

```
   ID BETWEEN   20 AND   29
OR ID BETWEEN  200 AND  299
OR ID BETWEEN 2000 AND 2999
```

I find it highly unprobable.

Comment: Very good answer. It explains why a like is forbidden in some of my critical production systems. They are just very costly to do. Dont get me wrong they are not all bad but can be very expensive to run.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL uses a [cost-based optimizer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizer-issues.html). It will evaluate the cost of using the index versus the cost of not using the index.

- If your table has only three rows it will make very little difference whether the index is used or not, so MySQL may choose either plan.
- Incorrect statistics may cause an index not to be used when it should have been.
- If you have more than two columns in your table and only a few rows then it may be cheaper to not use the index because since all rows have to be scanned anyway (there is no optimization for LIKE on a column of type int). There is little advantage to using the index when you are doing a full scan and have `SELECT *` (which, by the way, is a bad practice).

Having said that, I was unable to reproduce your results. MySQL always used the index when I tried your query.

See it online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04522/2)

Comment: my table has 161 records at the moment

Comment: @Anant: What do you mean by "at the moment"? Are you implying that this is likely to change soon? Is it likely to grow to over 100,000 at some point?

Comment: The number is going to change , but should be around 10,000

Comment: @Anant: You should optimize with the same type of data that you plan to use. Optimizing on a small number of rows won't give the same results.